# C#/ASP.NET Short code Translation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some data I'm showing in a few repeaters. I'm displaying the various fields using Eval(), and it's displaying correctly, but the data is using short codes for certain things.

For example:

```
db1 = Diabetes Type 1
db2 = Diabetes Type 2
tb  = Tuberculosis
```

etc etc

What I want to know is, if the Eval() is pulling up one of these short codes, how do I setup a conditional that will read the field, and adjust it to its proper long name?

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to replace the `Eval` by a method that translates it, such as:

```
<%# Translate(Eval("SomeField")) %>
```

And in `Translate`:

```
public string Translate(object value)
{
    if (value is int)
    {
        int intVal = (int) value;
        switch (intVal)
        {
            case db1:
                return "Diabetes Type 1";

            //etc
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Beware that the bound value is prototyped as object, so you need to cast it to what you know is inside.

Comment: When I try to make this method, it tells me "not all code paths return a value" while underlining the name of the method.

Comment: You always need to return something from the method.

Comment: What if I'm working with integers instead of strings?

Comment: I updated the sample. Of course, db1, in this case, should be some int variable.

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "int."

Comment: Also, what would need to change if all I wanted to do was have it display nothing if the value is 0, but just display normally if it's anything else?

Comment: Then it is a string, not an int! You told me it was an int!

Comment: It's a very simple case, you should be able to achieve that easily.

Comment: Even though I'm getting this error without running it? It's just telling me this error in the editor.

Comment: @Taborator You need to be able to understand the basics of handling objects, ints and strings, and how to create a method that returns a value.